# Logical function across multiple columns using "any" function

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to run a logical operation (multiple conditions) across many columns. I have written a query which is working fine. However, I want to shorten my code as I have to write several queries.

I have tried shortening the query using "any" and "brackets". However, the second query is running fine but giving me a different answer. Does "any" function work on multiple columns?

Here are my conditions -

1. any of the column (B2 to B5) has 1 & B1 <=2, then "Noissue"
2. any of the column (B2 to B5) has -99 & B1 <=2, then "Noissue"
3. B1 ==3, then "Noissue"
4. Rest is all issue

| Participate | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | Query1 | Query2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | -1 | -1 | -1 | -1 | -1 | Noissue | Noissue |
| 1 | -1 | 1 | -1 | -1 | 1 | Noissue | Noissue |
| 1 | -1 | -1 | -1 | -1 | -1 | Issue | Noissue |
| 2 | -1 | 1 | 1 | -1 | 1 | Noissue | Noissue |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | -1 | Noissue | Noissue |
| 1 | -99 | -99 | -99 | -99 | -99 | Noissue | Noissue |

I appreciate if anyone help me on reducing the code lines using different functions.

```
 mutate(Batch_v1, 
               case_when (
                 ((Batch_v1$B1 == 1 |  Batch_v1$B2 == 1 | Batch_v1$B3 == 1 | Batch_v1$B4 == 1 | Batch_v1$B5 == 1| Batch_v1$B6 == 1| Batch_v1$B7 == 1|Batch_v1$B8 == 1|Batch_v1$B9 == 1|Batch_v1$B10 == 1|Batch_v1$BOth == 1) & 
                    Batch_v1$Participate %in% c(1,2,-99))~"Noissue",
                 ((Batch_v1$B1 == -99 |  Batch_v1$B2 == -99 | Batch_v1$B3 == -99|Batch_v1$B4 == -99 |Batch_v1$B5 == -99|Batch_v1$B6 == -99|Batch_v1$B7 == -99|Batch_v1$B8 == 1|Batch_v1$B9 == -99|Batch_v1$B10 == -99|Batch_v1$BOth == -99) & 
                    Batch_v1$Participate %in% c(1,2,-99))~"Noissue",
                 Batch_v1$Participate ==3 ~ "Noissue",
                 TRUE ~ "Issue"))





mutate(Batch_v1, 
   case_when (
     ((any(Batch_v1[,2:6] == 1)) & Batch_v1$Participate %in% c(1,2,-99))~ "Noissue",
     ((any(Batch_v1[,2:6] == -99)) & Batch_v1$Participate %in% c(1,2,-99))~ "Noissue",
     Batch_v1$Participate ==3 ~ "Noissue",
     TRUE ~ "Issue"))
```

Comment: What are `query1` and `query2` on your example? Why the third and the first row have different `query1` values despite being all made by `-1`?

Comment: `any(Batch_v1[,2:6]` probably does not do what you think it does. It will operate on all values in the columns, not row-wise as you probably want.

Comment: In the description you say if B1==3 than "Noissue", but in your solutions its if Participate==3. Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

Batch_v1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    Query3 = case_when(
      any(B1:B5 == 1)   & Participate %in% c(1,2,-99) ~ "Noissue",
      any(B1:B5 == -99) & Participate %in% c(1,2,-99) ~ "Noissue",
      Participate == 3                                ~ "Noissue",
      TRUE                                            ~ "Issue"
      )
    )
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 9
# Rowwise: 
  Participate    B1    B2    B3    B4    B5 Query1  Query2  Query3 
        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1           3    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1 Noissue Noissue Noissue
2           1    -1     1    -1    -1     1 Noissue Noissue Noissue
3           1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1 Issue   Noissue Issue  
4           2    -1     1     1    -1     1 Noissue Noissue Noissue
5           2     1     1     1     1    -1 Noissue Noissue Noissue
6           1   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99 Noissue Noissue Noissue
```

The main problem with your second code is the function

```
any(Batch_v1[,2:6] == 1)
```

Let's take a look at

```r
Batch_v1[,2:6] == 1

#>         B1    B2    B3    B4    B5
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So `Batch_v1[,2:6] == 1` returns a data.frame of booleans. Applying `any` on this data.frame returns `TRUE` if `any` of the values inside this data.frame is `TRUE`. That's clearly not your desired behaviour.
Using `rowwise()` forces `any` to be applied... well... per row.

**Note:** Inside a `tidyverse`-pipe, you don't want to use `Batch_v1$B1` if you are refering on the current object you are working with. `Batch_v1$B1` for example refers to the *original* `Batch_v1`, without any transformations done. In this case, there is no real difference, but you shouldn't rely on this in general.

Comment: Thank you for the code. However, there is problem at my end. The code is giving out an error - object 'B2' not found. I could not run other code given by @TarJae - "Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : could not find function "across".

Comment: Updating your tidyverse-package should solve the issue with across. Are your columns named B1 - B5?

Comment: Yes, the columns are named same. I have issues with Rtools. I have reinstalled everything and the code is working fine. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We could uses `across` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(B2:B5, ~case_when(. == 1 & B1 <=2 ~ "Noissue",
                                    . == -99 & B1 <=2 ~ "Noissue",
                                    B1 == 3 ~ "Noissue",
                                    TRUE ~ "issue")
                  )
           )
```

Output:

```
  Participate    B1 B2      B3      B4      B5      Query1  Query2 
        <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1           3    -1 issue   issue   issue   issue   Noissue Noissue
2           1    -1 Noissue issue   issue   Noissue Noissue Noissue
3           1    -1 issue   issue   issue   issue   Issue   Noissue
4           2    -1 Noissue Noissue issue   Noissue Noissue Noissue
5           2     1 Noissue Noissue Noissue issue   Noissue Noissue
6           1   -99 Noissue Noissue Noissue Noissue Noissue Noissue
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Participate = c(3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), B1 = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, 1, -99), B2 = c(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -99), B3 = c(-1, 
-1, -1, 1, 1, -99), B4 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -99), B5 = c(-1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, -99), Query1 = c("Noissue", "Noissue", "Issue", 
"Noissue", "Noissue", "Noissue"), Query2 = c("Noissue", "Noissue", 
"Noissue", "Noissue", "Noissue", "Noissue")), problems = structure(list(
row = 6L, col = "Query2", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
file = "'test'"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Following is the error that I encountered - Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "across". I am trying install dev version (tidyverse) based on the link [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615137/cant-find-function-across-in-mutate

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we have to use logical conditions rowwise across many columns, two main approaches should usually be considered. These obviate the need for `rowwise()` and `Reduce()` in the alternative with `lapply/map %>% Reduce/reduce`, or complex `case_when()`statements.

-1) `rowSums(condition)`
-2) `if_any() / if_all()`

This question is most suited for a solution with `if_any()`.

**With `if_any()`**

```
Batch_v1 %>% mutate(query3 = ifelse(if_any(B2:B5, ~.x %in% c(-99, 1)) & B1<=2,
                                    "Noissue", "Issue"))
```

**With `rowSums()`**

```
Batch_v1 %>% mutate(query3 = ifelse(rowSums(across(B2:B5, ~.x %in% c(-99, 1)))>0 & B1<=2,
                                    "Noissue", "Issue"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  Participate    B1    B2    B3    B4    B5 Query1  Query2  query3 
        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1           3    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1 Noissue Noissue Issue  
2           1    -1     1    -1    -1     1 Noissue Noissue Noissue
3           1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1 Issue   Noissue Issue  
4           2    -1     1     1    -1     1 Noissue Noissue Noissue
5           2     1     1     1     1    -1 Noissue Noissue Noissue
6           1   -99   -99   -99   -99   -99 Noissue Noissue Noissue
```

There are some good answers to similar questions in here:
[Rowwise logical operations with mutate() and filter() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257561/rowwise-logical-operations-with-mutate-and-filter-in-r)
and here:
[R - Remove rows from dataframe that contain only zeros in numeric columns, base R and pipe-friendly methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754119/r-remove-rows-from-dataframe-that-contain-only-zeros-in-numeric-columns-base/67754388#67754388)
DISCLAIMER: I either asked or answered these questions